# How to add Observable<List><Items>> to List<Items> RxJava Android

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, retrofit2

In my repository I have a Retrofit call that returns an Observable>

```
 public Observable<List<Task>> getTasks() {

    final List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    return TaskService.networkCall().getTasks()
            .flatMap(new Func1<Response<ResponseObject>, Observable<List<Task>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<Task>> call(Response<ResponseObject> responseObjectResponse) {
                    List<Task> response = responseObjectResponse.body().getTasksResponse();
                    tasks.addAll(response);
                    return Observable.just(tasks); // this have the list of tasks - I checked
                }
            });
```

The problem I have when I try to add and return List in my viewModel here:

```
 public List<Task> getTaskList() {

    final List<Task> cache = new ArrayList<>();

    mSubscription.add(mDataManager.getTasks()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<List<Task>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(List<Task> tasks) { // List<Task> has data

           cache.addAll(tasks); // List<Task> cache is always 0 size

        }
    }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Throwable throwable) {

        }
    }));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in both cases your `List<>` get instantiated again every time the methods get called